# Squid caching issues

Tags: cache, squid

I'd like to create a cron job that will delete our squid cache and restart it. The reason I'm doing this is because when I upload a new build javascript code to our webserver, when I browse our app in browser pointed to our squid, i still get the old code even if I have cleared my browser's cache.

It starts working after I clear our squid's cache and restarting it.

Do I really need a job to do this or am I just missing a config in our squid? Of course, we still want caching but not when a new web app build has been uploaded.

Comment: From the first Google search: http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/OperatingSquid#I_want_to_restart_Squid_with_an_empty_cache

Comment: What? Looks like you didn't understand my post.

Comment: You want to clear and restart the cache. The link I sent refers to the section "I want to restart Squid with an empty cache". Script that into a cron. Or have I misunderstood your request?

Comment: Yup, you misunderstood it. I mentioned the issue that was happening. I was asking if there might be a config that I need to add in squid.conf for this caching issue to go away.

Comment: Ok, why don't you just add a Squid cache bypass entry for the domain(s) that you do not want to cache?

Comment: it's because we still want cache to take effect on those domains. So looks like the only way is to really clear the cache. Or maybe expire every 3 mins?

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused. You don't want to have your app traffic cached but you don't want to add a bypass because you want it cached?

Comment: No no no. That's not what I meant. The caching is working great until I upload a new application. The browser will still see old files even if I cleared the browser's cache.

Comment: Forgot to mention that our squid and webserver is in a development environment. Webserver will receive changes many times a day.

Comment: How about this: http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/OperatingSquid#How_can_I_purge_an_object_from_my_cache.3F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your squid.conf to ensure that there are no refresh_pattern lines telling Squid to disobey/ignore HTTP caching instructions. That should be all you need to do. Squid will do the revalidation (REFRESH/IMS) checking by default whenever it needs to, the rest is up to the origin server.

Ensure that your server produces Last-Modified, and if possible ETag headers on each response. Squid older than 3.5.21 need that to revalidate.

If your changes are at known regular intervals Cache-Control:max-age=N and Expires headers should be emitted that tell Squid when the next change will take place. Otherwise, if timing is unpredictable Cache-Control:no-cache header should be emitted.

You also need to ensure that your server produces the 304 responses properly when the content has not changed. If it does not, then look to your servers documentation for how to fix that.

Comment: That's what I did few days ago. I added no-cache, max-age 0, etc headers in the nginx endpoint. No one has come to me yet and asking "hey can you please clear the cache" :)

Comment: max-age=0 is probably going a bit too small, that essentially means dont cache it at all. The N is a count of seconds, so you could set it to a few tens or hundreds and get reasonable caching as well as responsiveness on updates. it also overrides the no-cache - so picking one would be best.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check that Squid is configured properly to check upstream on every cache request, and set the HTTP `If-Modified-Since` header on each request.

If the upstream server sends a response with `304 Not Modified`, then Squid can send the existing cache version. If the upstream server replies with a new version, then Squid can update its cache and send the new version of the file.

Comment: Oh that is cool. I'll try it when I upload a new build tomorrow. What part in the squid configuration do I check? Also, where do I put this - If-Modified-Since?